# Change width of div without affecting contents inside

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I would like to create a set of svg images and place it in a div. When that div gets resized (in javascript), I want the width to change, without changing what's inside it, giving the effect of the resized div covering up the contents (ex. cutting the div's width in half will make half the content inside hidden).

Is this possible through html?

Here is a [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2g3sh1s/). When you push the button, the div width changes to a smaller size. I want it to hide the portion of the svg outside of it.

```
<div id="container">

 <svg width="400" height="280">
  <rect x="50" y="20" rx="20" ry="20" width="150" height="150" style="fill:red;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:0.5"></rect>


  <rect x="90" y="50" rx="20" ry="20" width="150" height="150" style="fill:blue;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:0.5"></rect>
 </svg>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quick fix with just CSS, no JavaScript needed. You can hide what "overflows" with the overflow property.

Add overflow hidden to `#container`:

```
#container{
    width:50%;
    background-color:white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You can try this again with your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2g3sh1s/5/) modified

Also, there are a couple of other things going on in your fiddle: You are not using `==` in your conditional statements. And even if you were, you need a way to start things off with a dynamic width. So, here's a fixed up [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2g3sh1s/6/) that uses just the JS changes.

Lastly, I would do it slightly different in the way that I would add / remove classes based on if that class is already added to that element. You can check that out here on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2g3sh1s/8/)

Comment: I want it to change on command, not on load. So on load, everything will be shown, but when someone presses a button or performs an action, the width changes and hides the content.

Comment: @auto Did you try it? It does what you are wanting

Comment: Oh, okay, I see. Thank you. I can still use javascript. yes, this was easier than I thought.

Comment: @auto Yes, you could still use JS to solve it. is that the way you are hoping to go about it instead of CSS?

Comment: @auto, I've made a few more modifications to your fiddle. And you will see that there are two different examples included in my answer now. Just wanted to point out a couple more things.

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow:hidden or overflow:scroll to your CSS

```
#container{
  width:50%;
  background-color:red;
  Overflow:hidden;
}
```